# Finding different previous value in a list in python?

Tags: python

Let's say i have list output of 500 items. What i want is getting the previous value which is not the same of the last item.

For example:

List = [1,7,9,8,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5]

desired output : 8

I need my code the calculate previous different item. In my list, the last item is 5 and according to previous items, i need the first different number than the last one.

I searched google, but all i could find is the previous item compared to last or previous low/high values in the list which are not helping me at the moment.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: A simple loop: `for i in range(len(List) - 2, -1, -1): if List[i] != List[-1]:....`

Comment: What prevents you from getting the last item, then looping over the list from the end until you find an item that isn't equal to the last one?

Comment: these solutions are good. Johnny's solution takes a lil while though. Thanks Robert i asked it because maybe easier way to do that.

Comment: Another stupid solution `next(itertools.dropwhile(lambda x: x==lst[-1], lst[::-1]), None)`

Comment: I like your spirit, @StevenRumbalski!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach using [extended iterable unpacking](https://peps.python.org/pep-3132/) and [`next`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#next):

```
lst = [1, 7, 9, 8, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5]

last, *front = reversed(lst)
res = next((v for v in front if last != v), None)
print(res)
```

**Output**

```
8
```

The above approach is *equivalent* to the following for-loop:

```
last, *front = reversed(lst)

res = None
for v in front:
    if last != v:
        res = v
        break

print(res)
```

Answer (score 1):

Another solution would be to transfer the list into a dict (dicts are guaranteed to be ordered since Python 3.7), reconvert the resulting keys into a list and take the second last item:

```
>>> l = [1,7,9,8,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5]
>>> list(dict.fromkeys(l))[-2]
8
```

Note: this is probably quite slow for larger lists and not that readable, but I thought it would be fun

Comment: yes it is fun indeed :) but as you mention it works slow :(

Comment: @yktrcn: With a list of size 500 you really do not need to care about speed.

Comment: Is `[1,7,9,8,5,6,5,5,5,5,5]` a valid input?  With this code the result for that will be 5.